# How do I limit the movement of an image to certain areas of the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, limit, move

In my program, the user can move an image around on the canvas using either the arrow keys or the WASD keys. Currently the user can move the image off of the canvas. I have tried to write code to prevent the user from being able to do this, but it didn't seem to make any difference (There is no error, but the user can still move the image anywhere they want to). Is there a way to fix the code I already have, so that the user can no longer move the image off of the canvas?

```
#functions to move the player image on the level 1 canvas
def left_level1(event):
    if level1_playerImage_x >= 50:
        level1_canvas.move(playerImage, -10, 0)
        level1_playerImage_x == level1_playerImage_x -10
    
def right_level1(event):
    if level1_playerImage_x <= 1950:
        level1_canvas.move(playerImage, 10, 0)
        level1_playerImage_x == level1_playerImage_x +10
    
def up_level1(event):
    if level1_playerImage_y >= 50:
        level1_canvas.move(playerImage, 0, -10)
        level1_playerImage_y == level1_playerImage_y -10

def down_level1(event):
    if level1_playerImage_y <= 1450:
        level1_canvas.move(playerImage, 0, 10)
        level1_playerImage_y == level1_playerImage_y +10

#function to open the level 1 page
def level1():
    global level1_canvas, playerImage, level1_playerImage_x, level1_playerImage_y
    
    #defining the x and y coordinates of the playerImage
    level1_playerImage_x = 1800
    level1_playerImage_y = 1400
    
    #close levelSelection page and open level1 page
    root3.destroy()
    root4 = Tk()
    
    #binding KeyPress events to the pop up box
    root4.bind("<a>", left_level1)
    root4.bind("<d>", right_level1)
    root4.bind("<w>", up_level1)
    root4.bind("<s>", down_level1)
    root4.bind('<Left>', left_level1)
    root4.bind('<Right>', right_level1)
    root4.bind('<Up>', up_level1)
    root4.bind('<Down>', down_level1)
    
    #create a canvas for the level1 and put it into the root
    level1_canvas = Canvas(root4, height = 1500, width = 2000, bg = 'LightBlue3')
    level1_canvas.pack()
    
    #bring player image onto canvas
    player = PhotoImage(file = 'Player.png')
    playerImage = level1_canvas.create_image(level1_playerImage_x, level1_playerImage_y, image = player)
    exitSign = PhotoImage(file = 'exitSign.png')
    exitSignImage = level1_canvas.create_image(1900, 75, image = exitSign)
    
    mainloop()#end level1 page
```

Comment: You need `global level1_playerImage_x` at the beginning of `left_level1` and `right_level1`. Also you need `global level1_playerImage_y` at the beginning of `up_level1` and `down_level1`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I added this to my code but it still did not restrict the movement of the image. The user is still able to move the image off the canvas in each direction.

Comment: Also (I don't know why I didn't notice it earlier) but you are using a double equal sign instead of a singular equal sign here `... == .. + 10`. If you change those it should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, the program works now! Thank you so much!